# Reference request for an introduction to higher-order logic

Tags: reference-request, higher-order-logic

I'm looking for an introductory text or other materials on higher order logic, with a minimum of assumed background knowledge beyond first order logic.

Comment: It might help to say what you are interested in learning about HOL.  There are purely mathematical texts which describe the logic and its type theoretic properties, like normalization.  On the other hand, there are plenty of tutorials for the theorem provers, e.g. Isabelle/HOL, which use HOL as a logical base.  Those focus more on the axioms of HOL and how to build mathematics in it practically using a computer.  And finally there are papers connecting HOL to topos theory since a form of HOL is the internal language of a topos.

Comment: Also your background might help to.  Do you come from more of a logic/math background (say having taken a logic course in logic in undergraduate), or a CS background (where you learned functional programming)?  That might also impact what resources are best for you.

Comment: @JasonRute  Thank you. My background is a mix of computer science and math. I have studied some first order logic, Haskell and Lean. I'm interested in the syntax and semantics and how it generalizes from first order logic. I would like to implement a simple proof checker for it in Haskell and prove some properties about it in Lean.

Comment: I think then for the implementation side that you might be interested in HOL Light.  HOL Light's implementation is really light weight and is only a few hundred lines of OCaml code.

Comment: As far a syntax, it should be noted that yes HOL can be viewed as a continuation of first order logic (where you quantify over elements), second order logic (where you quantifier over elements and sets (or functions) of elements), third order logic (where you quantify over sets of sets of objects), ...  But most implementations of HOL also use type theory, so it looks less like FOL or SOL and more like functional programming.

Comment: Finally, for semantics,  Quine famously stated that Second Order Logic is "set theory in sheep's clothing", and that is even more true of HOL.  As such, any model of HOL is going to look like a model of set theory.  Once you start moving away from models of set theory, I think you are either going to get into programming language semantics (where the type theory of HOL describes the behavior of a programming language) or categorical semantics (where HOL describes the inner workings of a topos).  But either way, it will look and feel very different from FOL model theory.

Comment: @JasonRute "There are purely mathematical texts which describe the logic and its type theoretic properties, like normalization." What would you recommend for these?

Comment: I don’t know the perfect resource but I learned about normalization of simple type theory (which is similar to the type theory used in say HOL Light, except the later adds polymorphism) through Jeremy Avigad’s logic course notes which are now the book [Mathematical Logic and Computation](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/avigad/mathematical_logic_and_computation_toc.pdf).

Comment: @JasonRute Thank you!

Comment: @JasonRute It looks like the book is not yet published? Are the logic course notes available online?

Comment: They were not (publicly) online.  You could however email the author, Jeremy Avigad.  (It is a pity the book isn’t out yet.  I think both chapters 13 and 17 would be of interest to you.)

Comment: It appears that it may be set for release in September.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are asking on the proof assistant stack exchange, possibly the best approach would be to read a tutorial for one of the proof assistants using HOL.  Any good tutorial would describe the logic and how one can build mathematics in this logic.

I learned HOL via HOL-Light.  The [HOL-Light tutorial](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Ejrh13/hol-light/tutorial_220.pdf) covers the logic, how to construct common mathematical objects like the natural numbers, and how to do proofs in HOL Light.  Having said that, I don't know that I would really recommend HOL-Light, as it doesn't have a large base of users and it is not the most user-friendly system to work with (because you have to use an OCaml interpreter to interact with the theorem prover).

Possibly better would be to find a good tutorial for Isabelle/HOL. I think, but am not sure, that [Proving and Programming](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/prog-prove.pdf) is the recommended starting tutorial now.

Answer (score 3):

I found it useful to also read *books* on higher-order logic, several I can recommend:

- Stewart Shapiro, *Foundations without foundationalism* (which argues second-order logic is adequate for doing ordinary mathematics, preferable to first-order logic, and examines higher-order logic)
- Peter B. Andrews, *An Introduction to Mathematical Logic and Type Theory: To Truth Through Proof*.

As preposterous as it sounds, I also found Johnstone's *Sketches of an Elephant*, vol. II, chapter D particularly good for discussions of categorical aspects of logic (specifically, the functorial behaviour of interpretations, and generalizing ideas to higher-order logic).

Comment: Book recommendations are more than welcome. Thank you.